# VueJS - Update data after API call from mounted() function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using an API call in the `mounted()` function and would like to set the received data to the variable `graphData`. I checked the API call and it works fine, since I can see the data in the console. When I comment out the section, where I hardcode the data, the variable `graphData` in the data section gets also updated. So I assume there is something wrong with setting the variable outside the `mounted()` function.

```
  mounted() {
/*      this.graphData = {"2019-12-30T14:06:36.001Z": 44,
          "2019-12-30T14:06:28.002Z": 132,
          "2019-12-30T14:06:28.003Z": 376,
          "2019-12-30T14:06:36.004Z": 452,
          "2019-12-30T14:06:36.005Z": 452,
          "2019-12-30T14:06:36.006Z": 448}; */
    var i = 0;
    fetch("https://3.23.40.69:9001/app/usageUnitForCustomer/1421")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
      const time = data.event_time;
      const unit = data.unit;
         for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
           if (time[i] !== time[i + 1]) {
            this.graphData[i] = "'" + time[i].toString() + "'" + ':' + unit[i] + ",";
            console.log(this.graphData[i]);
           }
        }
      })
  },
  data() {
      return {
        graphData: [],
  }
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks!

Comment: this in `fetch` is not bound to Vue instance. You're setting wrong data.

Comment: If you console.log(data), do you get anything?

Comment: Yes, it is the data in the commented section, so the expected output.

Comment: @deathangel908 How to bound it to the vue instance?

Comment: Oh NVM, you're already using arrow funct, use vue.set to update an array by index, Vue 2.x doesn't track new indexes

Comment: @deathangel908 do you mean like this `this.graphData.$set(i,"'" + time[i].toString() + "'" + ':' + unit[i] + ",");`

Comment: you are using `graphData` both as an array `[]` as an object `{}`.

Comment: It'd be `this.$set(this.graphData, i, "'" + time[i].toString() + "'" + ':' + unit[i] + ",")`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-set and https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats. However, the data structure you're building is quite different from the format shown in the commented out section. Also, given the `if` check, you're going to end up with gaps in your array. Perhaps using `push` would be preferable to keep entries consecutive. If you use `push` you also wouldn't need to use `$set`.

Comment: @skirtle: Thanks that worked out. I just used `push` to insert the data into the array.